# Calculate Event: Insert Comment In Cell If Value and Delete Any Comments If Not Value

Tags: vba, excel

The following code is a change event handler that searches col B for the word "fee" and inserts comments in the 3 adjacent cols if the word "fee" is found in col B:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

Set rng = Range("B:B")

If Not rng Is Nothing Then

    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If cell.Value = "fee" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).AddComment "fi"
            cell.Offset(0, 2).AddComment "fo"
            cell.Offset(0, 3).AddComment "fum"
        End If
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

The above code works fine.

I also want to search col B and delete any existing comments in the 3 adjacent cols if the word "fee" does not occur in col B. So, I added an Else statement:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

Set rng = Range("B:B")

If Not rng Is Nothing Then

    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If cell.Value = "fee" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).AddComment "fi"
            cell.Offset(0, 2).AddComment "fo"
            cell.Offset(0, 3).AddComment "fum"
        Else:
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Comment.Delete
            cell.Offset(0, 2).Comment.Delete
            cell.Offset(0, 3).Comment.Delete

        End If
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

This results in the runtime error: "Object variable or With block variable not set", and the debugger points to

```
cell.Offset(0, 1).Comment.Delete
```

VBA seems to want me to use a With statement, but the With permutations I've tried result in the same error. Any thoughts?

Follow up with Andy's correct suggestion. The code adds comments if the condition is met, clears comments if it is not:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("B:B")

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        cell.Offset(0, 1).ClearComments
        cell.Offset(0, 2).ClearComments
        cell.Offset(0, 3).ClearComments
        If cell.Value = "fee" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).AddComment "fi"
            cell.Offset(0, 2).AddComment "fo"
            cell.Offset(0, 3).AddComment "fum"
        End If
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA is not suggesting that you use With. The error occurs if you attempt to Delete a comment when there isn't one.

You can either check for the existence of a comment before attempting to `Delete` it:

```
Dim cmt As Comment

Set cmt = Range("A1").Comment
If Not cmt Is Nothing Then
    Range("A1").Comment.Delete
End If
```

or, simpler, use `ClearComments`:

```
Range("A1").ClearComments
```

Also note that your first code is on the `Calculate` event, not `Change`.

Delete the colon after `Else` as well - always have Else as a single word on its own line; this colon may cause issues.

**Added** following OPs coded solution: Your code could be simplified:

```
If Not rng Is Nothing Then

    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        cell.Offset(0, 1).ClearComments
        cell.Offset(0, 2).ClearComments
        cell.Offset(0, 3).ClearComments
        'or even just
        'cell.Range("B1:D1").ClearComments

        If cell.Value = "fee" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).AddComment "fi"
            cell.Offset(0, 2).AddComment "fo"
            cell.Offset(0, 3).AddComment "fum"
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Andy, per your instructions I have deleted the colon after the Else, and replaced cell.Offset(0, 1).Comment.Delete with cell.Offset(0, 1).ClearComments. The sub crashes with the error "Application defined or object-defined error." I believe this is because if comments already exist in the cells in question, then the AddComment does not work. The cells may or may not contain comments a priori. Ihe code should add or clear comments depending on the value in col B, and skip adding or clearing if the conditions are already met. Thanks.

Comment: So you can use the same code from my answer to check whether a comment exists before adding one, or just use ClearComments and then AddComment.

Comment: No worries. However, your code could be simplified - see my answer again. You can just clear any comments, and only add them again if necessary.

Comment: Yes, that is simpler and equally effective. I have made the revision. Thanks again.